# Polymer Binding dont work for CSS only in IE

Tags: html, css, binding, polymer

I have a binding to change the color of my div with a polymer binding. it work except in IE.

```
<div horizontal layout class="navigation" style="background-color:{{toolbarColor}};">

</div>
<script>
        Polymer('mapscontroller-element', {

            currentPoint: 0,
            toolbarColor: "#0099cc",
            ...

currentPointChanged: function() {
                this.toolbarColor = this.toolbarColorArray[this.currentPoint];
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is the question?  I spent 5 seconds googling and was able to find [polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/databinding-compat.html) that explains why there are compatibility issues as well as potential workarounds for the issue.  **Don't be lazy!**